# Why does my thread not wake up? (Java)

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm loosely following [a tutorial on Java NIO](http://rox-xmlrpc.sourceforge.net/niotut/) to create my first multi-threading, networking Java application. The tutorial is basically about creating an echo-server and a client, but at the moment I'm just trying to get as far as a server receiving messages from the clients and logging them to the console. By searching the tutorial page for "EchoServer" you can see the class that I base most of the relevant code on.

My problem is (at least I think it is) that I can't find a way to initialize the queue of messages to be processed so that it can be used as I want to.

The application is running on two threads: a server thread, which listens for connections and socket data, and a worker thread which processes data received by the server thread. When the server thread has received a message, it calls `processData(byte[] data)` on the worker, where the data is added to a queue:

```
1.  public void processData(byte[] data) {
2.      synchronized(queue) {
3.          queue.add(new String(data));
4.          queue.notify();
5.      }
6.  }
```

In the worker thread's `run()` method, I have the following code:

```
7.  while (true) {
8.      String msg;
9.
10.     synchronized (queue) {
11.         while (queue.isEmpty()) {
12.             try {
13.                  queue.wait();
14.             } catch (InterruptedException e) { }
15.         }
16.         msg = queue.poll();
17.     }
18.
19.     System.out.println("Processed message: " + msg);
20. }
```

I have verified in the debugger that the worker thread gets to line 13, but doesn't proceed to line 16, when the server starts. I take that as a sign of a successful wait. I have also verified that the server thread gets to line 4, and calls `notify()`on the queue. However, **the worker thread doesn't seem to wake up**.

In the javadoc for `wait()`, it is stated that

> The current thread must own this object's monitor.

Given my inexperience with threads I am not exactly certain what that means, but I have tried instantiating the queue from the worker thread with no success.

Why does my thread not wake up? How do I wake it up correctly?

---

### **Update:**

As @Fly suggested, I added some log calls to print out `System.identityHashCode(queue)` and sure enough the queues were different instances.

This is the entire `Worker` class:

```
public class Worker implements Runnable {
    Queue<String> queue = new LinkedList<String>();
    public void processData(byte[] data) { ... }
    @Override
    public void run() { ... }
}
```

The worker is instantiated in the `main` method and passed to the server as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Worker w = new Worker();
    // Give names to threads for debugging purposes
    new Thread(w,"WorkerThread").start();
    new Thread(new Server(w), "ServerThread").start();
}
```

The server saves the `Worker` instance to a private field and calls `processData()` on that field. Why do I not get the same queue?

---

### Update 2:

The entire code for the server and worker threads is now available [here](http://pastebin.com/VZLUH2DT).

I've placed the code from both files in the same paste, so if you want to compile and run the code yourself, you'll have to split them up again. Also, there's abunch of calls to `Log.d()`, `Log.i()`, `Log.w()` and `Log.e()` - those are just simple logging routines that construct a log message with some extra information (timestamp and such) and outputs to `System.out` and `System.err`.

Comment: Where are you instantiating `queue`?  Is it the same object in both cases for which you have shown code?

Comment: Owning the thread's monitor is accomplished by synchronizing on that object.  The `synchronized (queue)` code requires that the thread running that code gets the monitor (for exclusive access) lock on that object.   It should be noted also that calling `wait()` will release the monitor lock, but it will be reacquired when `wait()` returns.

Comment: You might try adding `System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(queue)` in both bits of code to see that you are actually dealing with the same `queue` object.  (Or just look at the object's identity in your debugger.)  May we assume nothing else is calling `queue.wait()`?

Comment: @Fly: Tried that, and it turns out the instances aren't the same. Please see my update.

Comment: paste the entire code. you almost did it anyway and there has to be some detail that's still missing

Comment: @soulcheck: I've pasted the code now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to guess that you are getting two different `queue` objects, because you are creating a whole new `Worker` instances.  You didn't post the code that starts the `Worker`, but assuming that it also instantiates and starts the `Server`, then the problem is on the line where you assign `this.worker = new Worker();` instead of assigning it to the `Worker` parameter.

```
    public Server(Worker worker) {
            this.clients = new ArrayList<ClientHandle>();
            this.worker = new Worker(); // <------THIS SHOULD BE this.worker = worker;
            try {
                    this.start();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e("An error occurred when trying to start the server.", e,
                                    this.getClass());
            }
    }
```

The thread for the Worker is probably using the `worker` instance passed to the Server constructor, so the Server needs to assign its own worker reference to that same Worker object.

Comment: This was of course the solution. It's so simple it's embarrassing :P Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You might want to use [`LinkedBlockingQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html) instead, it internally handles the multithreading part, and you can focus more on logic. For example :

```
// a shared instance somewhere in your code
LinkedBlockingQueue<String> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<String>();
```

in one of your thread

```
public void processData(byte[] data) {
   queue.offer(new String(data));
}
```

and in your other thread

```
while (running) {  // private class member, set to false to exit loop
   String msg = queue.poll(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
   if (msg == null) {
       // queue was empty
       Thread.yield();
   } else {
       System.out.println("Processed message: " + msg);
   }
}
```

**Note :** for the sake of completeness, the methode `poll` throws in `InterruptedException` that you may handle as you see fit. In this case, the `while` could be surrounded by the `try...catch` so to exit if the thread should have been interrupted.

Comment: But I'm trying to create a *non-blocking* I/O implementation. Wouldn't a `BlockingQueue` completely defy that goal?

Comment: if each thread are well separated, no, since the blocking does not occur to the whole application, but only in the threads concerned to be blocked, waiting for data to process. "Non blocking" does not mean that nothing ever blocks, but the application is responsive as much as physically possible all the time. Besides, if there's nothing to process, why would your application consume CPU looping for nothing? Better it waiting for some data then, no?

Comment: and in response to `BlockingQueue`, the class does not *block* the whole application, but only under certain conditions (ie. queue full, no data available yet, etc.), otherwise it does not block anything else. For example, `offer` does not block unless the queue is full, and `poll` does not block unless some timeout is specified, etc. This is to ensure thread safety in concurrent access and data availability (data integrity) when needed, etc.

Comment: I've tried the blocking queue now, and although it makes the code somewhat simpler, it still doesn't help the issue: the two threads are for some reason not accessing the same queue.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that `queue` is an instance of some class that implements the `Queue` interface, and that (therefore) the `poll()` method doesn't block.

In this case, you simply need to instantiate a single queue object that can be shared by the two threads.  The following will do the trick:

```
Queue<String> queue = new LinkedList<String>();
```

The `LinkedList` class is not thread-safe, but provided that you always access and update the queue instance in a `synchronized(queue)` block, this will take care of thread-safety.

I think that the rest of the code is correct.  You appear to be doing the wait / notify correctly.  The worker thread should get and print the message.

If this isn't working, then the first thing to check is whether the two threads are using the same queue object.  The second thing to check is whether `processData` is actually being called.  A third possibility is that some other code is adding or removing queue entries, and doing it the wrong way.

Comment: That may be a good assumption.  He says the debugger shows the code never gets to that line though.

Comment: This is the way I orinally instantiated the queue, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

`notify()` calls are lost if there is no thread sleeping when `notify()` is called. So if you go `notify()` then another thread does `wait()` afterwards, then you will deadlock.

You want to use a semaphore instead. Unlike condition variables, `release()/increment()` calls are not lost on semaphores.

Start the semaphore's count at zero. When you add to the queue increase it. When you take from the queue decrease it. You will not get lost wake-up calls this way.

**Update**

To clear up some confusion regarding condition variables and semaphores.

There are two differences between condition variables and semaphores.

1. Condition variables, unlike semaphores, are associated with a lock. You must acquire the lock before you call `wait()` and `notify()`. Semaphore do not have this restriction. Also, `wait()` calls release the lock.
2. `notify()` calls are lost on condition variables, meaning, if you call notify() and no thread is sleeping with a call to `wait()`, then the `notify()` is lost. This is not the case with semaphores. The ordering of `acquire()` and `release()` calls on semaphores does not matter because the semaphore maintains a count. This is why they are sometimes called counting semaphores.

Comment: His `wait()` and `notify()` calls are done when the thread has the monitor, and he's checking for empty, so I don't see anything wrong with the code that is posted, but it's not enough code to know what the problem is.

Comment: No, wait() calls release the lock. In his code, the producer is calling notify() before the consumer is calling wait() so the notify() call is getting lost.

Comment: The `wait()` releases the lock only after it is waiting, so it should not miss the notify but he could let the `wait()` timeout and see if there's something in the queue to test that.

Comment: No wait() releases the lock immediately and puts the thread to sleep so other threads can enter the monitor and call notify(). If wait() only released the lock after waking-up, then how is another thread going to call notify()? Remember that in order to call notify() a thread must have the lock. In other words, a thread must be inside the monitor to call notify(). Condition variables are for scheduling threads inside a monitor. Threads must be in the monitor (have the lock) in order to use the condition variable.

Comment: The thread is added to the wait set for the object and then the thread releases its lock(s) on the object while it waits. The other thread cannot call `notify()` until the first thread is successfully in `wait()` as in step 1 here: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/memory.html#17.8

Comment: I see what you're saying. The consumer won't call wait() if the queue is not empty so the problem of lost notify()'s is avoided. So lost notify()'s are probably not the issue. I'm too tired to think about this right now, so I'll take a take a look at that link tomorrow and I'll take a closer look at his code.

Comment: By inserting conditional breakpoints I've been able to verify that `wait()` is called before `notify()`, so this is not the problem...

Answer (score 0):

> In the javadoc for wait(), it is stated that
>
> ```
> The current thread must own this object's monitor.
> ```
>
> Given my inexperience with threads I am not exactly certain what that
>   means, but I have tried instantiating the queue from the worker thread
>   with no success.

They use really bizarre and confusing terminology. As a general rule of thumb, "object's monitor" in Java speak means "object's lock". Every object in Java has, inside it, a lock and one condition variable (`wait()`/`notify()`). So what that line means is, before you call `wait()` or `notify()` on an object (in you're case the queue object) you much acquire the lock with `synchronized(object){}` fist. Being "inside" the monitor in Java speak means possessing the lock with `synchronized()`. The terminology has been adopted from research papers and applied to Java concepts so it is a bit confusing since these words mean something slightly different from what they originally meant.

Comment: OK, thanks for the clarification! Even though it doesn't really help me solve my problem, it at least tells me what my problem is *not* =)

Answer (score 0):

The code seems to be correct.

Do both threads use the same queue object? You can check this by object id in a debugger.

Does changing notify() to notifyAll() help? There could be another thread that invoked wait() on the queue.

Answer (score 0):

OK, after some more hours of pointlessly looking around the net I decided to just screw around with the code for a while and see what I could get to. This worked:

```
private static BlockingQueue<String> queue;

private BlockingQueue<String> getQueue() {
    if (queue == null) {
        queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<String>();
    }
    return queue;
}
```

As [Yanick Rochon pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8798115/38055) the code could be simplified slightly by using a `BlockingQueue` instead of an ordinary `Queue`, but the change that made the difference was that I implemented the Singleton pattern.

As this solves my immediate problem to get the app working, I'll call this the answer. Large amounts of kudos should go to @Fly and others for pointing out that the `Queue` instances might not be the same - without that I would never have figured this out. However, I'm still very curious on *why* I have to do it this way, so I will ask a new question about that in a moment.