# Why do I need the Singleton pattern in this multithreaded application?

Tags: java, multithreading, singleton

I recently had [a problem with two threads sticking in deadlock because they weren't monitoring the same object the way I thought they were](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8798049/why-does-my-thread-not-wake-up-java). As it turned out, implementing the Singleton pattern [solved the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8810470/38055). **But why?**

I only instantiated one instance of the class of which the object was  a private property, so I expected it to be effectively singleton anyway.

---

For the sake of completeness of the question, here is also some code illustrating the difference:

Before the Singleton pattern was implemented:

```
class Worker {
    private BlockingQueue q = new LinkedBlockingQueue();

    public void consume(String s) {
        // Called by thread 1.
        // Waits until there is anything in the queue, then consumes it
    }

    public void produce(String s) {
        // Called by thread 2.
        // Puts an object in the queue.
    }

    // Actually implements Runnable, so there's a run() method here too...
}
```

The threads were started like this:

```
Worker w = new Worker();
new Thread(w).start();

// Producer also implements Runnable. It calls produce on its worker.
Producer p = new Producer(w);
new Thread(p).start();
```

Now, when I examined the queues that were actually used in `produce()` and `consume()`, `System.identityHashCode(q)` gave different results in the different threads.

With the singleton pattern:

```
class Worker {
    private static BlockingQueue q;
    private BlockingQueue getQueue() {
        if(q == null) {
            q = new LinkedBlockingQueue();
        }
        return q;
    }
    // The rest is unchanged...
}
```

Suddenly, it works. Why is this pattern necessary here?

Comment: Seeing as this is not compilable code, its hard to pinpoint what might have been going on in your actual implementation.

Comment: Nothing you are showing here would produce the condition you are describing.

Comment: He posted the Server and Worker code here: http://pastebin.com/VZLUH2DT    Having the thread-launching code that is posted here helps, too, of course.

Comment: You also should not use the singleton pattern (i.e., the `static` qualifier) because you would not be able to have more than one Worker.  If you tried to use more than one Worker, then they would all use one and the same `queue`, which would be pointless except in some strangely contrived situation.  :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you are creating a `new Worker()` inside the `Server` constructor.  You have this:

```
public Server(Worker worker) {
    this.clients = new ArrayList<ClientHandle>();
    this.worker = new Worker();  // This is the problem.


// Don't do this in the Server constructor.
this.worker = new Worker();

// Instead do this:
this.worker = worker;
```

Comment: Since you don't need to use a Singleton pattern here, I would avoid it, too.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the pseudo code you've posted, it is not actually the singleton pattern that made the difference, but simply the use of `static`.  In your first example, the queue is not declared static, so each instance of `Worker` is going in instantiate its own individual `LinkedBlockingQueue`.  When you declare it `static` in the second example, the Queue is created at the class level and shared among all instances.

Based on the code you posted in your other question, the error is right here on the last line:

```
public Server(Worker worker) {
        this.clients = new ArrayList<ClientHandle>();
        this.worker = new Worker();
```

So your statement

> I only instantiated one instance of the class of which the object was
>   a private property, so I expected it to be effectively singleton
>   anyway.

is inaccurate.  You're isntantiating a new Worker in every new server, not reusing the one passed in.